# syncing code with repo/backup

Tags: development-process, solo-development, backups

I am doing a small software project on my local PC. I'm the only person working on this. I'd like to back this up to the cloud every day so that if anything happens to my HDD I have a various copies going back in time.

I have a box account although that seems to want to sync continuously and with constant file changes with code I don't really want this.

Can anyone recommend any site or software that will allow me to back up to an external location online? I'm happy to manually kick off this process at the end of each day.

Comment: Sounds like you need a [Source Control Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_management)? [GitHub](http://github.com/) is a popular option nowadays.

Comment: product or service recommendations are explicitly off-topic per [help/on-topic]. http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a software project, you should absolutely be using version control, even if you're the only developer. It'll also take care of the backup aspect if you use a repository that's on another machine. I recommend [Git](http://git-scm.com/). [GitHub](https://github.com/) is a good repository host and free for open source projects.

For my general purpose backup needs I've been very happy with [CrashPlan](http://www.code42.com/crashplan/). It runs silently in the background and backups what you want automatically, so that the backups are always up to date (the backup interval is configurable). It keeps multiple old versions of files, which is a life saver when you have deleted or overwritten the wrong files. CrashPlan is free if you backup to your own machines or disks - the online backup costs a little.